# Stripe Checkout freezes web page when focusing on input field

Tags: javascript, php, firefox-addon, checkout, stripe-payments

I want to UPDATE this to notify viewers that adding an exception for Stripe.com in Priv3 fixes this issue. However, this may be an extreme edge case as the Stripe Developers were unable to reproduce this error on Mac in Firefox 31.1.0. I was using a Debian based OS with IceWeasel. So there may be some edge case issue here as well as some other external interference.

---

Using PHP with CodeIgniter and the Stripe Library functions, I have the basic Stripe Checkout configuration setup. Nothing extra and nothing special.

Here it is on the checkout page:

```
<form action="/stripe" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key=<?php echo STRIPE_PRIVATE_KEY; ?>
    data-amount=<?php echo str_replace('.','',$a['fee']); ?>
    data-name="Listing Fee"
    data-description="listing-subscription"
    data-image="/128x128.png">
  </script>
</form>
```

However, during testing using Firefox and focusing on an input field of the Stripe checkout js form, the form immediately goes away and the whole web page freezes which means I am unable to click on any link.

I have figured this is (probably) due to privacy plugins I have like Ghostery and AddBlock Plus, Disconnect and Self-Destructing cookies. When using my Chrome browser or even a different saved profile for Firefox that has no plugins on it, the form works.

Has anyone experienced this and found a fix for it? I can't expect my users to have their browsers setup the way I want them to. So I am wondering (and hoping) there is a fix instead.

UPDATE:

I have singled it down to the Priv3+ addon. Advising my users to add an exception to the plugin for Stripe.com is my temporary solution.

Comment: Have you contacted Stripe support about this?

Comment: I was unable to find a forum and their Help and Support page only has about 5 Q&A's per subject with no link that I could find that allow for questions to be asked. There is a feedback link but that doesn't seem to be an appropriate avenue. Could you guide me into the right direction of where to ask my question?

Comment: You can email stripe directly from here: https://support.stripe.com/email

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have sent a question using the link above. I have also made a temporary fix as posted in the UPDATE above. I will shoot over to the Priv3+ devs and see if I can find a forum to post for them as well.